# Test framework for API calls within VS Code extensions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I've got a small VS Code extension in TypeScript that uses the Axios library to make API calls. I've used the [recommended](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension) Mocha framework to script tests, and am running these locally and via Github Actions.

I've now added `c8` to give me code-coverage reports, and wish to improve coverage including the Axios calls. I found [this article](https://vhudyma-blog.eu/3-ways-to-mock-axios-in-jest/) which recommends adding the `jest` framework. However I found that gave type clashes with Mocha, and it seems it's a bad idea to have more than one test framework.

Is there a simple example of how to mock Axios calls with Mocha?

Comment: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki#mocks-stubs--spies contains a list of libraries that mocha recommends for mocking in mocha.

Comment: Thank you! Of these, which do you consider the simplest for a JS newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to mock the requests *to* an API, why not mock the API itself?

https://github.com/nock/nock is a good library that is [recommended by mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki#mocks-stubs--spies) that you can try out for your use case.